# How to import components or utils using same name from multiple path in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The project structure looks like

```
- src
    - business
        - sales
            - views
            - components
            - filter.js
            - router.js
            - ...
        - marketing
            - views
            - components
            - filter.js
            - router.js
            - ...
- App.vue
- main.js
- ...
```

main.js looks like

```
import filter from "@sales/filter";
import filter from "@marketing/filter";
Vue.use(filter);

import router from "@sales/router";
import router from "@marketing/router";
Vue.use(filter);
...
```

Then I got syntax error
**Identifier 'filter' has already been declared**,
**Identifier 'router' has already been declared**

How to import filter, router, or common things using the same name from multiple paths in vue.js?

Comment: Import filter as filterSecond from ...

Answer (score 2):

This is related to javascript imports, the only alternative is to rename the name of the imported element in the file where you want to import it

If you have default exports you can rename them directly like:

```
import salesFilter from "@sales/filter";
import marketingFilter from "@marketing/filter";

Vue.use(salesFilter);
Vue.use(marketingFilter);
```

If you have named exports

```
import { filter as salesFilter } from "@sales/filter";
import { filter as marketingFilter } from "@marketing/filter";

Vue.use(salesFilter);
Vue.use(marketingFilter);
```

Comment: Ok so in that case you still need to import as shown in the default version but this time you have to call the function and no need to use `Vue.use(...)` instead just call it like

`salesFilter.install()`

Answer (score 0):

You could rename one of the imported functions like :

```
import filter from "@sales/filter";
import {default as filter1 } from "@marketing/filter";
Vue.use(filter);
Vue.use(filter1);
```